# Jest: Mongoose and koa server dont close connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, koa, supertest

When called afterAll function I call close methods of server and mongoose, in console output that Mongodb connection closed but when I watch connections count I mongo cli it the same and tests finish with success but node doesnt close script what can be problem ?

before: [image]

[image]

after close mongoose connection: [image]

While I do not suspend execution of the script by ctrl-c

I have mongoose connection:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { MONGO_URI } from '../config'

mongoose.Promise = Promise

export default {
  connect () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI)

      const connection = mongoose.connection

      connection.on('error', reject)
      connection.on('open', (data) => {
        resolve(connection)
      })
      connection.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Mongodb connection closed')
      })
    })
  }
}
```

app:

```
import Koa from 'koa'

const app = new Koa()

...

export default app
```

Test:

```
import r from 'supertest'
import mongodb from 'db/mongodb'
import app from 'app'
import CategoryModel from 'modules/categories/models/category'

describe('Categories routes', () => {
  let mongoConnection
  let server

  beforeAll(async () => {
    mongoConnection = await mongodb.connect()
    server = await app.listen()
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoConnection.close()
    await server.close()
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    await mongoConnection.dropDatabase()
  })

  describe('/GET', () => {
    it('records exist', async () => {
      const { body } = await r(server).get('/api/categories')

      expect(body).toHaveProperty('data')
      expect(body.data).toHaveLength(2)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Did you found an answer?

Comment: Yes, need close mongoose connection, or add --forceExit